# Method is not executed

Tags: java, methods, execution

I am trying to grasp a basic Java concept and I cant figure out why my method is not get executed. I would like to print out `substring` from word bunny if it has more than 3 characters, else print out the original string. My code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    static String bunny = "bunny";

    public static String subStringBunny(String bunny) {
        if (bunny.length() > 3) {
            bunny = bunny.substring(2, 4);
        }
        return bunny;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("this is substring from bunny: " + bunny);
    }
}
```

It still prints the original string so I suppose the `subStringBunny` method does not get executed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "*I cant figure out why my method doesnt get executed*" better question: what makes you think that it should be executed?

Comment: To check if the method gets executed you  could use a debugger or simply add another System.out.println(....).

Comment: BTW you have two separate variables with same name (one local one class field). That is one of ingredients in recipe for problems in code.

Comment: @Pshemo Clrearly the OP doesn't control the basics. Please provide an answer instead of being a smartass. It doesn't help him.

Comment: Thank you guys for help, I just realized a big thing and that really encouraged me!

@Pshemo I thought the code is executed line by line and did not realize methods must be called.

Comment: @StavAlfi From my experience things stay in our memory longer if we remember how we came up with them. If we hear some fact (even if we agree with it) we tend to forget about it faster then if we came up with it ourselves. By asking questions like "*What* did you expect do happen?" "*Why* did you expect such thing?" I am trying to encourage others to describe their assumptions. Then we can start reviewing and correcting them. So if not giving others fish but trying to encourage them to get (or even better, build) a rod is being "smartass" then lets just agree to disagree.

Comment: The context of your comment is clear. "_What_ did you expect.. " is not equal to "_Why_ did you expect.. ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling `subStringBunny` method from the `main` method. This code should do what you're trying to achieve:

```
package com.company;
public class Main {    
    static String bunny = "bunny";    
    public static String subStringBunny (String bunny) {
        if (bunny.length() > 3) {
            bunny =  bunny.substring(2,4);
        }    
        return bunny;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println("this is substring from bunny: " + Main.subStringBunny(bunny));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a need to specify the method called by "Main" even though it IS within the Main class? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @mosses There isn't a need to do it - i'm just being explicit. `System.out.println("this is substring from bunny: " + subStringBunny(bunny));` would work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the method. You most do this:

```
System.out.println("this is substring from bunny: " + subStringBunny(bunny));
```